# angularjs vs twitter bootstrap tabs javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making my first steps with angularJS. In the "code school" video (http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/level/2/section/2/video/1) there is a sample code that makes tabs in angular:

HTML

```
  <section class="tab" ng-controller="TabController as tab">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(1)}">
        <a href ng-click="tab.setTab(1)">Description</a></li>
      <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(2)}">
        <a href ng-click="tab.setTab(2)">Specs</a></li>
      <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(3)}">
        <a href ng-click="tab.setTab(3)">Reviews</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-show="tab.isSet(1)">
      <h4>Description</h4>
      <blockquote>{{product.description}}</blockquote>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="tab.isSet(2)">
      <h4>Specs</h4>
      <blockquote>Shine: {{product.shine}}</blockquote>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="tab.isSet(3)">
      <h4>Reviews</h4>
      <blockquote></blockquote>
    </div>
  </section>
```

JavaScript:

```
  app.controller('TabController', function(){
    this.tab = 1;

    this.setTab = function(newValue){
      this.tab = newValue;
    };

    this.isSet = function(tabName){
      return this.tab === tabName;
    };
  });
```

I know that twitter bootstrap has its own JavaScript for managing dynamic tabs (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs).

My question is: is angularjs using bootstrap javascript here? I guess not. And if not (while this means angular is using only bootstrap's CSS), then why is angular reinventing the wheel = implementing new code that does the same thing as bootstrap's javascript code? I mean, why writing different code that does the same stuff, why not to use existing code?

Maybe it's just a matter of this tutorial - but is there a way to make angular use native bootstrap's javascript?

Comment: Bootstrap is integrated into angular here (including tabs). http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinventing the wheel? They are only using `ng-show`, which just changes the display style in your element to `none`.

Angular has no problem to use anyone scripts, you only have to do it the angular way. In this case it is called directives (most cases when you are going to manipulate DOM this is the way).

So for angular directives you can use `template` or `templateUrl`, `template` you give a string, `templateUrl` you give a file path. In your case I recommend you to place a new html file and write there your tabs content.

so in you tabs.html file

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" class="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" class="profile">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" class="messages">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" class="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

your directive should look something like this, according to [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

```
myapp.directive('theNameOfMyDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'the path to my html file', you can use only template too and writte your html as string, but in your case I think it is more clean if you do it in a diferent file
        link: function (scope,element){
            // angular.element() this is similar to $() in Jquery or Jquery()
            angular.element(element).find('.profile').on('click', function (e){
                e.preventDefault()
                $(this).tab('show');
            });
            angular.element(element).find('.home').on('click', function (e){
                e.preventDefault()
                $(this).tab('show');
            });
            //some other tabs
        }  
    }
});
```

since we restrict our directive to be E (Element), we have to add this html to render our tabs wherever we need them

```
<theNameOfMyDirective></theNameOfMyDirective>
```

for more info of custom directives http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/custom-directives.html

Answer (score 4):

bootstrap provides one-way binding data. Howerver, angularJS supplies two-way binding. I suggest you should take a look at angular-ui. If you want use bootstrap with angularjs, you shoud search keyword "**custom directive angularjs**".